# Which GPU for ethOS?

Tags: mining, ether, ethos

I have bought MSI motherboard with ethOS SSD. I have Nvidea GPU but it's not starting up the mining process. Is there any particular brand GPU I have to use with ethOS?

Comment: ethOS is for AMD series GPU cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe they have to be AMD GPU's not NVidia.

> Supports up to 10 AMD RX Series GPUs: Including support for Intel Z170/X/270/X Chipsets and AMD Ryzen.
>
> Supports up to 8 AMD R7/R9 Series GPUs: Any 2GB+ HD 7000 series, any R9 200/300/Fury/Nano.
>
> Supports up to 8 AMD GPUs: Any 2GB+ HD 7000 series, any R9 200/300/Fury/Nano, and any RX 400/500 series.

See features list :
http://ethosdistro.com/

Answer (score 2):

Features
Boots and mines: Automatic IP/hostname assignment, no need to install any drivers, configure XWindows, or compile any software.
Supports up to 10 AMD RX Series GPUs: Including support for Intel Z170/X/270/X Chipsets and AMD Ryzen.
Supports up to 8 AMD R7/R9 Series GPUs: Any 2GB+ HD 7000 series, any R9 200/300/Fury/Nano.
Supports up to 8 NVIDIA GPUs: Any 2GB+ GTX 900 and GTX 1000 series.
...

Answer (score 0):

I use NVIDIA and EthOS with no issue. There are particular miners in EthOS that will only work on AMD or NVIDIA. Make sure you are setting your globalminer flag correctly depending on the coin you wish to mine.